# Evaluate the double integral $ \iint_D 2x\cos\!\left(y\right)+5 \ dA $ over the region D which is bounded by $y = 0, y = 2x^{2} $and $x = 1.$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Evaluate the double integral $\displaystyle \iint_D 2x\cos\!\left(y\right)+5 \ dA $over the region D which is bounded by $y = 0, y = 2x^{2} $and $x = 1.$

$\displaystyle \iint_D 2x\cos\!\left(y\right)+5 \ dA = \int_a^b\int_c^d 2x\cos\!\left(y\right)+5 \ dy \ dx$

a = 0, b = 1

c = 0, y = 2(?)

why is y not equal $2$?

$y = x^2$ and $x = 1$ intersect when $y = 2$

Wouldn't the double integral be:

$\int_0^1\int_0^2 2x\cos\!\left(y\right)+5 \ dy \ dx$

p.s. [here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v863C.png) the screenshot

Comment: If you let $x:0 \to 1$ and $y:0 \to 2$, you're integrating over a _rectangle_. Make a sketch of the region $D$ to see that this is not what you want.

Comment: @StackTD well I did,  [link](http://i.imgur.com/mmmFDjZ.jpg), drawn on a 2d plane, and then you can imagine that whatever surface is the red region, it just extends towards you and beyond (z-axis). No?

Comment: Yes, but you don't have to visiualize the function you're integrating to set up the integral boundaries: all you need is a good view of the (red) region $D$. I'll refer to your sketch in an answer.

Comment: I elaborated in an answer; hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a good idea to let $x$ run from $0$ to $1$. Referring to your sketch of the region $D$, you then need to find the limits for $y$ so that you run exactly through the red area: no more and no less.

Position yourself at an arbitrary $x$, somewhere between $0$ and $1$, below the $x$-axis. Let $y$ increase: you encounter the (red) region $D$ at $y=0$, this is where you start integrating. You leave the region when you cross the blue curve, corresponding to $y=2x^2$. This is where you **stop** integrating. So you end up letting $y$ run from $0$ to $2x^2$.

Continuing to $y=2$ (you only want this at $x=1$, but **not** for all the $x$ values $0 \le x < 1$!) would give you a complete rectangle and this is not what you want.

It should be clear from your sketch that the upper boundary of the region is not a constant (like $2$), but a function of $x$.

Comment: I think I'm getting it... but how come, so far when setting boundaries for y... I just figured out what the rightmost/leftmost x point corresponds in y -axis, and that's it....

Comment: I don't fully understand your question, I think... Perhaps you can clarify?

In any case: for a region like this, you can choose wether you take fixed limits for $x$ or for $y$. But then you will have variable limits for the _other one_ (as a function of the fixed, outer one) because with fixed limits for both, you'll always integrate over a rectangle (sketch this!). The boundary functions determine what these variable limits will be and when they're given in the form $y=f(x)$, it's usually the easiest to take fixed limits for $x$ and the variable ones for $y$.